# Failed CSV import to Postgresql // Delete all character before first integer in csv file bash

Tags: bash, postgresql, csv, sed

I after merging three different csv I got a file in the following format 
, 
1501274700442, 1.17562, 1.17569

What bothers me is the comma at the beginning of each line in a script, I've tried to remove it, but after using

```
grep -v '^,' f_77.csv > f_88.csv
sed '/^,/ d' f_77.csv > f_88.csv
sed 's/,//1' f_77.csv > f_88.csv
```

the output remains the same, moreover, after opening the file in libre office it looks like there's no comma there, only two empty lines, but issuing

```
sed '/^$/d' f_77.csv > f_88.csv
```

changes nothing.

I try to import to build a script that would import data to postgresql database in real time. Here's the postgresql part :

```
psql -U postgres -d q1_17eurusd -c "SET datestyle = 'ISO,DMY'"
psql -U postgres -d q1_17eurusd -c "CREATE TABLE tmp (time bigint, ask real, bid real)"
psql -U postgres -d q1_17eurusd -c "\copy tmp (time, ask, bid) from '/prd/pipeline/stream/f_77.csv' delimiter ',' CSV"
psql -U postgres -d q1_17eurusd -c "insert into realfun select * from tmp"
psql -U postgres -d q1_17eurusd -c "DROP TABLE tmp"
```

But when I try to import this only line I got

```
SET
CREATE TABLE
ERROR:  missing data for column "ask"
CONTEXT:  COPY tmp, line 1: ""
INSERT 0 0
DROP TABLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct snippet for initial commas removal is:

```
sed 's/^,//' f_77.csv > f_88.csv
```

Comment: for some reason it didn't work. simple more +2 f_77.csv > f_88.csv did the job thanks!

Comment: It did. Probably you don't have initial commas in that file, maybe they are preceded by a space. `more +2` removes two initial lines of input, so you have lost that data.

Comment: yup, this file is messed up. it's a output of at least ten other scripts that modify the initial csv file. most of the data I get in this stream are duplicate values, so I'm ready to sacrifice some data to have a steady pipeline. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: It works fine here:

```
nd@postgres=# create table t(f1 text, f2 numeric, f3 numeric, f4 numeric);
CREATE TABLE
nd@postgres=# copy t from stdin with csv;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> , 1501274700442, 1.17562, 1.17569
>> \.
COPY 1
nd@postgres=# table t;
┌──────┬───────────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│  f1  │      f2       │   f3    │   f4    │
╞══════╪═══════════════╪═════════╪═════════╡
│ ░░░░ │ 1501274700442 │ 1.17562 │ 1.17569 │
└──────┴───────────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
(1 row)
```

Could I to ask: what is the particular problem?